# MonoTouch MySQL Database Access

Tags: mysql, mono, xamarin.ios, provider

Is there a MySQL provider compatible with MonoTouch for iOS?

Can [Mono provider for MySQL database](http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL) be used with MonoTouch?

Comment: I never tried MySQL support but MonoTouch's provide `System.Data` and support for Sqlite and SQL server. Postgress support (Npgsql) is also known to work (but not shipped with MT). Note that most people prefer putting a web facade (e.g. a web service) between their applications and the database servers (and that will work with MT).

Comment: I can confirm MySQL c# provider does not work out of the box, but I agree with @poupou put an intrmediate layer i.e. WebService sou you can better handle disconection or network failures remember you are on a mobile escenario ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no compatible MonoTouch MySQL provider cause of the missing functionality of System.Data (http://bit.ly/HlKN71).

IMHO it's good that there is just a local Sqlite provider. Just put something like a REST in between your database and your mobile app to get this done.